# When using Radius Networks Android IBeacon library in android.app.Service, it didn't work

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

I am using Radius Networks Android IBeacon library. But when I try to use it in service ,it didn't work, just like the problem in this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439299/ranging-ibeacons-in-service-thread#. I can get a good performance in Activity, but when I used it in Service, it didn't work. If you want to see my code, please see the above link， my code is same as his.
At the same time, I can see a log err:
Class not found when unmarshalling: com.radiusnetworks.ibeacon.service.StartRMData.
I really need your help！

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the comments at the bottom of the [referenced question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22439299/ranging-ibeacons-in-service-thread#), you will see that the problem was that the code could not successfully send toast messages from the service during the ranging callback.  Using `Lod.d` to log messages about the iBeacon detections showed detections worked fine.

Did you try this?  If your code is exactly the same, presumably this will solve your problem, too.  If not, you will need to post your code so we can figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful assistance. I have found the problem by chance. In my AndroidManifest.xml code, I registered my own service like this:<service android:name=".BeaconService" android:label="FounderBeaconService" android:process=":message"></service>. When I delete android:process=":message", my program worked well. Now I am still trying to figure out the reason, but I hope to get your answer, I'm sorry to disturb you so much.